# Okta unable to access jenkins server

Tags: jenkins, okta

I integrated jenkins with Okta using SAML2.0 plugin.

Issue: When i click on jenkins app in the OKTA url it is redirecting request to https://jenkins.xxxx.com/samlLogout/ and displaying message "You are now logged out of Jenkins, however this has not logged you out of SAML".

I want to login to jenkins using OKTA Credentials but okta redirecting request to logout url and displaying the above message.

Please lemme know how can redirect request to jenkins home page(where my jobs are located)

Answer (score 3):

You should first check jenkins.log. I had the same issue with Jenkins version 2.235.3 and saml plugin 1.1.6 . I was seeing below error in the logs.

```
SAMLException: Authentication issue instant is too old or in the future
```

As per https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000087231-SAML-Authentication-issue-instant-is-too-old-or-in-the-future

**Sync servers by Installing NTPD**
a. Install NTPD in each of the machines is running services to integrate: IdP Provider as well as Jenkins in this case.

b. If you install the NTP service after IdP Provider/Jenkins has already been installed in your network, you should restart the IdP Provider/Jenkin service after NTP has been successfully installed.

**Maximum authentication time**

a. On the IdP side, decrease the time users are being retained to a value less than 24 days.

b. Delete browser cookies and login again.

***Note***: Deleting browser cookies may solve you problem temporary.

Answer (score 1):

Just clearing the cookies did the job